# Is it possible to have htaccess if else type rewrite conditions and rewrite rules?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache-config

I am trying to write an htaccess file that essentially does this:

```
if(requested file == "some-file.php" || requested file == "some-file2.php" || requested file == "some-file3.php")
   then Rewrite to redirector.php?uri=some-file.php <- substitute requested file without passing any parameters
else
// existing rewrite conditions from silverstripe
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* sapphire/main.php?url=%1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Is this possible using htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

I would think all you need to do is place your 3 unique requested files as 3 `RewriteRule`s at the top, above those `RewriteCond`'s:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule /(some-file.php) http://test.dev/redirector.php?uri=$1 [L]
RewriteRule /(some-file2.php) http://test.dev/redirector.php?uri=$1 [L]
RewriteRule /(some-file3.php) http://test.dev/redirector.php?uri=$1 [L]

// rest of Rewrite Stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(some-file\.php|some-file2\.php|some-file3\.php)$ redirector.php?uri=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your solution:

```
# if files are know, redirect and stop:
RewriteRule ^(some-file|some-file2|some-file3)\.php$ redirector.php?uri=$1.php [QSA,L]

# files that were not known go here:
# existing rewrite conditions from silverstripe
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* sapphire/main.php?url=%1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Nota:
I've removed:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
```

Which is useless. If you wanted to test "not empty", this should have been:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^$
```

Olivier